# Does the mounting orientation or side of a heat-sink matter?

Tags: heatsink

Imagine a transistor is normally screwed to a heat-sink as below:

[image]

If I screw the transistor in another orientation or from the the outer surface of the heat-sink would it affect the thermal resistance? I need to mount one through same heat-sink hole but from the outer surface of the heat-sink.

edit:

So I have the following heatsink:
[image]

But I want to mount this way:

[image]

Comment: Seems convection would be severely compromised. (Unless you have forced air flow).

Comment: so u mean the thermal resistance will increase a lot? :(

Comment: Thermal resistance will probably increase since it will difficult airflow (i.e. air heats and moves up, if the fins are horizontal, this will be hindered). You haven't mentioned if you have forced air flow, i.e. fans yet. In which case the orientation of the fins will probably make less of a difference.

Comment: theres no air flow. it will be in a closed box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mounting direction of the heatsink is not important. Only the airflow is.

1. If you use natural convection then the airflow should be able to rise from the lowest part up for all the fins of the heatsink.
2. If you use forced convection then the airflow should be forced along all the fins of the heatsink.

In computers you can even find processor cooling with a ventilator on top and forcing the airflow down over the fins of the heatsink.

Therefore only the total approach determines the limitations of the heatsink position.

Comment: theres no air flow in my case. the circuit will be in a closed box. so it doesnt matter in my case?

Comment: Always. In that case you have natural convection from the bottom of the box to the top. Therefore the fins must be positioned vertical. Maybe even some holes in the PCB to improve convection.

Comment: It would be great to see the quantative effect of this mounting the other way I mean. Unfortunately data sheets do not provide anything about it.